# How to concatenate CSV Files with Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

New on Robotframework, I would like to concatenate several CSV files into one. I am reading the CSV library but I have some difficulties to understand it well. Does anyone would have a solution ?

Update 2.0 :

I succeed to copy data from csv to a new one wit h a For loop, compact in a key word now (Concatenate)

I still have one problem, How to apply this loop on each document successively  in a folder ?
I try to use this :

```
FOR  ${Item}  IN  ${fileDirectory}
   @{csvDictList}    read csv file to list    ${Item}
   Concatenate   @{csvDictList}
END
```

But I get a permission error

Any idea ? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have any code to support your idea? Perhaps you can try something and tell us the result, then we can help you in a way that doesn't feel like we're working instead of you.

Comment: sorry I modified my first message